# PHP Curl - Session has expired

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to login to a remote site using CURL but I just keep getting the error message your session has expired, please re-login.

```
$username="xxxxxx"; 
$password="yyyyyyyy"; 
$url="https://remotesite.com/my.activation.php3"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "username=".$username."&password=".$password; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 

// check for errors before close
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

The cookie file is writeable and something is getting written to it. Any ideas what I can try to keep the session going?

Comment: Try enabling `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`?  Without having an actual error message text or knowledge of the site you're POSTing to, helping you with this may prove difficult.

Comment: I can show you the site with it being publically available just not provide my login details etc :P 

http://bit.ly/14loB1I

Comment: Think it might be because in cookie.txt, two of the cookies are getting deleted:

FALSE / TRUE 1330888968 MRHIntranetSession deleted

Is there a way for me to edit this so it isn't getting deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the [correct option](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for `CURLOPT_COOKIE*`.

`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` - The name of a file to save all **internal cookies** to when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close.

`CURLOPT_COOKIE` - The contents of the "Cookie: " header **to be used in the HTTP request**. Note that multiple cookies are separated with a semicolon followed by a space (e.g., "fruit=apple; colour=red")

`CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` - The **name of the file containing the cookie data**. The cookie file can be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style headers dumped into a file. If the name is an empty string, no cookies are loaded, but cookie handling is still enabled.

---

Additionally, enabling `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` may be of assistance when debugging cURL.

Comment: I'm sorry. Really new to this. Confused as to what I'm meant to be doing to get this to work :(

Comment: What's the contents of your `cookies.txt` file?  If it's actual cookie data, you should be using `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` instead of `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`.  If you need to hit a homepage, pick up a cookie, then carry the cookie forward, leave it as `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`.

Comment: # Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

remotesite.com FALSE / TRUE 0 uRoamTestCookie TEST
remotesite.com FALSE / TRUE 1330892310 MRHIntranetSession deleted
remotesite.com FALSE / TRUE 1330892310 MRHIntranetSpecial deleted
remotesite.com FALSE / TRUE 0 MRHSession 84b5a408f4e360f46865e71e1fca9e5b
remotesite.com FALSE / TRUE 0 VHOST standard

Answer (score 0):

use `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);`